# What is the syntax of the @Override annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I recently found that ( [http://www.javabeat.net/articles/30-annotations-in-java-50-2.htmlthe](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/30-annotations-in-java-50-2.html) )syntax of the @Override annotation  is

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
    @Target(ElementType.RUNTIME)
    public @interface Override 
    {
    }
```

But I think the following.Since it can be applied only to methods and since it inform this to compiler.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    public @interface Override 
    {
    }
```

Please tell me which one is correct. Please explain, if i am wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are wrong; it is defined (according to [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html)) as

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Override
```